# Is it possible to nest block styles in the theme.json

Tags: theme.json

In the theme.json file I can set styles for the `core/verse` block.

My designs dictate that if the editor were to nest the `core/verse` block inside of a `core/cover` block, some styles should be different for the `core/verse` block.

Obviously I can put those separate styles in the stylesheet, but I'm curious if I can nest rules for one block inside of another in the theme.json.

Anyone know if this is possible and/or can you point me to some good resources detailing what theme.json can/can't do?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same and found a solution in the documentation ​[Filtering `theme.json` client side](https://gutenberg.10up.com/reference/Themes/theme-json/#filtering-themejson-client-side) provided by the 10up crew.

They wrote:

> That isn't possible on the server because we cannot access the actual state of the block consuming the `theme.json` settings on the server

> In order to allow for these types of contextual settings a new client side hook called `blockEditor.useSetting.before` was introduced in WordPress 6.2.

The code-example in the 10up docs is -with subtle changes- probably from [one of the 6.2 dev-notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/02/28/custom-settings-wordpress-6-2/) post by @ndiego. His code sample was:

```
import { select } from  '@wordpress/data';
import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks';

/**
 * Disable text color controls on Heading blocks
 * when placed inside of Media & Text blocks.
 */
addFilter(
    'blockEditor.useSetting.before',
    'myPlugin/useSetting.before',
    ( settingValue, settingName, clientId, blockName ) => {
        if ( blockName === 'core/heading' ) {
            const { getBlockParents, getBlockName } = select( 'core/block-editor' );
            const blockParents = getBlockParents( clientId, true );
            const inMediaText = blockParents.some( ( ancestorId ) => getBlockName( ancestorId ) === 'core/media-text' );

            if ( inMediaText && settingName === 'color.text' ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return settingValue;
    }
);
```